# How to use node global vars in ejs script code?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm new to ejs and node-js. I started a node project and defined some global vars in my main `index.js` file at the root directory as follow:

```js
global.urlBack = "http://localhost:3300";
global.urlFront = "http://localhost:8080";
...
```

After that in `/views/index.ejs` directory I have a code as below:

```js
// in codes.js file
let myUrl = requestUrl;  // "requestUrl" is not recognized here
// some other codes
```

```html
<%- include('partials/header'); %>
    <main>
       <section>
        <p>some texts</p>
        <!-- some other elements... -->
        <span><%= requestUrl %></span>
       </section>
    </main>
    <script src="../static/codes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

That **requestUrl** variable is something that I pass by an express route like this one:

```
resp.render("index", {
      amountData: amountData,
      emailData: emailData,
      requestUrl: urlBack
    });
```

It could be recognized in `html` part of **ejs** file, but could not in `js` part.  How could I access the value of that global vars in my "codes.js" file?

Answer (score 0):

I actually could not found any solution that could use my global vars defined in `index.js` main file in my `codes.js` file that used in ejs file. But I decided to set my global vars in a file called "config.json" on public directory (same folder that ejs file is located) and use them in both **"codes.js"** and main **"index.js"** as follow:

> config.json:

```
{
    "request": "url of request",
    "front": "http://localhost:8080",
    "back": "http://localhost:3300",
    ....
}
```

Then in **"index.js"** file:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'public/config.json'), 'utf8'));
console.log(config.request);

global.configVar = config;

....
```

And in my "codes.js" that now is using `<script type="module" src="../static/codes.js"></script>` I imported the same json file as follow:

```js
import myJson from './config.json' assert {type: 'json'};
console.log(myJson.request);
....
```

That way I could use my global vars in both places, but the problem of my method (import assertions) is (if I am not wrong) only supported by **Chrome** browsers.

So if anyone could help me that find a solution that works in all browsers, please post another answer in this question. Thanks.